# How to validate a form with jQuery validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form that submits data to a database with ajax. I am trying to validate the form fields with [jQuery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) but I can't get it to work at all. The forms seems to ignore the validation code. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Many thanks.

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#message").hide();


    $("#edit_profile").validate({   //Validate

        //validation rules go here
        rules: {
            user_name: {
                required: true
            },
            user_email: {
                required: true,
            }
        },
    messages: {
            user_name: "error.",
            user_email: "error."
        },
        //End Validation

    $("#submit").on("click", function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

    var formdata = $(this.form).serialize();
            $.post('update_profile.php', formdata,
                function(data) {
                    $("#message").html(data);
                    $("#message").fadeIn(500);
                    $("#message").fadeOut(500);
                });
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

The Form

```
<!--FORM STARTS HERE--->

 <div class="form-group">
 <form class="" action="" id="edit_profile"  method="post">
              <label>
                Name
              </label>
              <input id="user_name" name="user_name" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $user_name ; ?>" value="<?php echo $user_name ; ?>" class="form-control input-md"
              >
            </div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <label>
                Email
              </label>
              <input id="user_email" name="user_email" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $user_email; ?>" value="<?php echo $user_email; ?>" class="form-control input-md"
              required="">
            </div>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-green pull-right" id="submit">

              Save
            </button>
   </form>
   <!--FORM ENDS HERE--->
<div id="message"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll write a proper answer after seeing some flaws in your code.

Use the [submitHandler](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) property to pass a function that will be executed when form is valid.

The function comes with two arguments `form` element and `event` instance, which you can use for your AJAX call.

```
$("#edit_profile").validate({  
    rules: {
        user_name: {
            required: true
        },
        user_email: {
            required: true,
        }
    },
    messages: {
        user_name: "error.",
        user_email: "error."
    },
    submitHandler: function (form, e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('update_profile.php', $(form).serialize(), function(data) {
            $("#message").html(data);
            $("#message").fadeIn(500);
            $("#message").fadeOut(500);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: So this code does verify the fields bit for some reason he form is no longer getting submitted. Nothing in the console is getting posted?

Answer (score 1):

As the validator is automatically called on form submit.
In this case no form is submitted.

> Put the ajax call in submitHandler.

or use

```
if (!$("#edit_profile").valid()) {
return false;
}
```

before

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: by calling the valid() on form , you are triggering the same thing which validator plugin triggers on form submit

Answer (score 1):

I think you should place the code for submission into the `submitHandler`property of the object you pass to `.validate()`. Have a look at the docs:

https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

The code you posted is syntactically incorrect since you put the `$().on('click')` stuff inside the object you pass to `.validate()`.